# Elixir mix test set color to default to enabled

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

In my project I can run the command `mix test --color` which adds some colored output to the terminal. I would like to set this globally, so I can just run `mix test` and it automatically picks up that I want the output colored.

What I've tried...

1. I've searched the online elixir docs about global configuration and global mix configuration.
2. I've tried `mix help` too and couldn't see anything about global configuration.
3. I've tried `mix help test` as well, it doesn't seem clear to me here how to add the option to the `mix.exs` file, or if it's possible to set global options somewhere.

I feel like this is probably possible, but after not coming up with anything I thought I'd ask here.

Answer (score 5):

I am not aware of the system-wide, global setting. It might be easily done, though, on a per-project basis with `:aliases` option given to what `MyApp.MixProject.project/0` callback in your `mix.exs` file returns.

```rb
defmodule MyApp.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :my_app,
      version: "0.1.0",
      ...
      aliases: [test: "test --color"], # this
      ...
    ]
  end
  ...
```

[Aliases](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.html#module-aliases) are designed to provide exactly this functionality: `mix test` would now call `mix test --color` under the hood.

Comment: This is great, thank you, works on a per project basis perfectly. Can these flags be set as environment variables I wonder, I can't see anything on that, given there's no global mix config file (like .git or .npmrc) that's the only other way I know of that normally allows for that kind of overrides

Comment: AFAIK, aliases cannot be set globally. This is indirectly proven by [`Mix.Tasks.Help.load_aliases/0`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/5e3ef21c241e6c17bfc6c710f54503560a74036e/lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/help.ex#L121-L125) source code _and_ the lack of any mention of aliases in [Environment variables](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.html#module-environment-variables) section.